Asyncio with mssql & FastAPI
The environment is a docker image that deploys on eks cluster.
The docker image is 'python3.10-slim'.
I tried to develop a connector class which responsible for making async communication between FastAPI (Uvicorn ASGI based on) and mssql.
I tried to use pymssql+aiodbc, it works fine, but in the first load, the app is stuck and holds the connection with the db and prevents the client from accessing to app (the same API that open sesaion vs the db).
I solved that issue by increasing the number of pods but I want to make a better solution.
How could I implement an async connector with mssql, in order to use aiodbc+pymssql with async engine?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read how to create a minimal reproducible example. Noone will be able to help you if you don't share any code.
